# expo-secure-storage does not keep data upon uninstalling the app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using `react-native` for the application.
I want to save the some data and re-used it upon `re-installing` the application.

I am using `expo-secure-storage`.

```
export const setSecureItem = async (
  key: string,
  value: string,
  options?: SecureStore.SecureStoreOptions,
) => {
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value, options);
};

export const getSecureItem = async (
  key: string,
  options?: SecureStore.SecureStoreOptions,
) => {
  return await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key, options);
};
```

on my manifest

```
 <application
      ...
      android:hasFragileUserData="true"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:fullBackupContent="true"
      android:allowClearUserData="false"
      tools:replace="allowBackup">
```

It is working fine on my emulator, uninstalling and reinstalling the app I can still used the data.

[image]

But on the real device, it is not working.

--
Also, is it possible to support different versions?

Any idea?

Thanks!